ADO how to access output variable from stage dependedOn by stage depended on by current stage
I am trying to access variable from a stage A in stage C. Stage C depends on stage B and stage B dependents on stage A.
Is there a Direct way to do so?
I am able to access it in stage B but not in stage C.
I am trying to access it by doing something like this:
- stage: deploy_dev
    dependsOn: build
    displayName: Deploy to DEV
    jobs:
      - deployment: deploy_dev_job
        displayName: Deploy to DEV
        environment: Dev
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - template: templates/deploy-template.yml
  - stage: deploy_dev1
    dependsOn: deploy_dev
    displayName: dep Deploy to DEV
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - deployment: deploy_dev_job
        displayName: Deploy to DEV
        environment: Dev
        variables:
          - name: devOutput
            value: $[stageDependencies.deploy_dev.deploy_dev_job.outputs['deploy_dev_job.devOutput']]
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - script: |
                  #!/bin/bash
                  echo devOutput: $(devOutput)
  - stage: deploy_stage
    dependsOn: [deploy_dev1]
    displayName: Deploy to STAGE
    condition: succeeded()
    pool: AFC-Devops-AWS-Agent
    jobs:
      - deployment: deploy_stage_job
        displayName: Deploy to STAGE
        environment: Stage
        variables:
          - name: devOutput
            value: $[stageDependencies.deploy_dev.deploy_dev_job.outputs['deploy_dev_job.devOutput']]
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - template: templates/deploy-template.yml
                  parameters:
                    devOutput: devOutput


So, the solution is that to access the variable form stage A in stage C, you should also make sure the stage C  dependsOn stage A.

If I remember correctly, in order to set a variable or condition using syntax stageDependencies.stageXXX... you need to include stageXXX in the dependencies of the stage where the variable or condition will be set.
So instead of:
  - stage: deploy_stage
    dependsOn: [deploy_dev1]

Include the stage where the variable was set as well - in this case, deploy_dev:
  - stage: deploy_stage
    dependsOn: 
      - deploy_dev
      - deploy_dev1


Yes that is 1 way but issue is there is 1 stage for validation which blocks deployment to prod. and prod is only dependent on it. and if possible I don't want to change it and keeping adding extra depends on as last option.

@siddheshpadhye if deploy_dev should always run there won't be any problem in adding it to the dependencies of the other stage.
If that's not the case you can set another output variable in the validation stage and then reference it in the prod deployment stage.

Changing Validation stage is not a option for me, its actually handled by different team and we dont have permission to do any changes to it.

@siddheshpadhye well you're running out of options. The simplest/easiest solution is the one I already provided in my answer.
Other workarounds will add extra and unnecessary complexity to your pipeline. For example, instead of having an output variable try writing the value to a file and publish it as an artifact, and then download that artifact in the prod stage. But, as I already mentioned, it adds unnecessary complexity.
I have no other suggestions to give.

Yeah seems like that, will go for adding stage dependencies.
Thank you!

@siddheshpadhye if my solution helped you please consider accepting and/or upvoting it.
